# How to append new parameter to the url on slider slide action

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jquery slider

```
        slide:  function(e, ui){
        var value = $('#changeTableSlider').slider('value');
        $(this).attr("href",$(this).attr('href')+'&minSquaredAverage'=value);  
        }
```

On slider slide action I want to add new parameter to the current url. Firebug is currently giving me error on this like "invalid assignment left hand side". Need help please.??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equal sign needs to be **inside** the single quote. You also need to use a `+` to concatenate the value of `value` on to the string. See below.

```
slide:  function(e, ui){        
    var value = $('#changeTableSlider').slider('value');
    $(this).attr("href",$(this).attr('href')+'&minSquaredAverage=' + value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the `=` sign **inside** the single-quotes!

Answer (score 0):

this is because you have an error here

```
$(this).attr("href",$(this).attr('href')+'&minSquaredAverage'=value
```

it should be

```
$(this).attr("href",$(this).attr('href')+'&minSquaredAverage=value');
```

otherwise you try to sum a string.